# Use rego to compare before and after values from list of inputs

Tags: open-policy-agent, rego

When I run the following, I can compare the values for parameter instance_class and count the number of discrepancies:

```
modifies_instance_class[resource_type] = num {
    some resource_type
    resource_types[resource_type]
    all := resources[resource_type]
    modifies := [res |  res:= all[_]; res.change.after.instance_class != res.change.before.instance_class]
    num := count(modifies)
}
```

However, I'd like to be able to use the same block of code to compare different parameters values contained in my list my_params. I've tried the following but this doesn't work.

```
my_params = {"instance_class", "engine_version", "identifier"}

modifies_instance_class[resource_type] = num {
    some resource_type
    some parameter
    resource_types[resource_type]
    my_params[parameter]
    all := resources[resource_type]
    modifies := [res |  res:= all[_]; res.change.after.parameter != res.change.before.parameter]
    num := count(modifies)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As Patrick East mentioned, there are a couple issues. I thought I'd break down each one and provide a bit more detail. Here's the final version that I came up with: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/rl1p43N5HR

## 1st problem: lookup the field using the `parameter` var

The expression `res.change.after.parameter` looks up the field named `"parameter"` in the the object referenced by `res.change.after`. In other words, [the syntax `foo.bar` is sugar for `foo["bar"]`](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#references). The expression `foo["bar"]` selects the field `"bar"` (string 'bar') from the value `foo`. To fix this, change `res.change.after.parameter` to `res.change.after[parameter]`. Now `parameter` refers to the variable.

```rb
modifies_instance_class_V1[resource_type] = num {
    some resource_type, parameter
    resource_types[resource_type]
    my_params[parameter]
    all := resources[resource_type]
    modifies := [res | res:= all[_]; res.change.after[parameter] != res.change.before[parameter]]
    num := count(modifies)
}
```

## 2nd problem: make `modifies_instance_class` generate one value per key

The second problem is that rule will generate conflicting values for the `modifies_instance_class` document. Rules of the form `p[x] = y { ... }` generate a JSON document named `p` where `x` and `y` are the keys and values (respectively). OPA has to treat conflicting values for the same key as runtime errors.

For example, imagine OPA contains the following data:

```rb
resource_types = {"servers"}

resources = {
  "servers": [{
      "after": {"instance_class": "ic1", "identifier": "id1"},
      "before": {"instance_class": "ic2", "identifier": "id1"}
  }]
}
```

The data indicates there is one `resource_type` (`"servers"`) and one server. The data for the server indicates the `instance_class` field changed.

When OPA evaluates the rule, it will search for variable assignments that satisfy all of the expressions in the rule body:

```rb
# This is the rule body from above.
some resource_type, parameter
resource_types[resource_type]
my_params[parameter]
all := resources[resource_type]
modifies := [res | res:= all[_]; res.change.after[parameter] != res.change.before[parameter]]
num := count(modifies)
```

In this case,
OPA finds values for `resource_type`, `parameter`, `all`, `modifies`, and `num`. Ignore the `all`, `modifies`, and `_` variables for now.

In this case, OPA will find two sets of variable assignments:

```rb
{resource_type: "servers", parameter: "instance_class", num: 1}
{resource_type: "servers", parameter: "identifier", num: 0}
```

The problem is that the rule generates a mapping from `resource_type` to `num`. In this case, that produces `{"servers": 1}` and `{"servers": 0}`. This is the conflict. Which document is correct?

To resolve this we can simply move the `my_params[parameter]` expression into the body of the array comprehension.

```rb
modifies_instance_class_V2[resource_type] = num {
    some resource_type
    resource_types[resource_type]
    all := resources[resource_type]
    modifies := [[res, parameter] |   # NOTE: this generates an array of resource/parameter tuples now.
        some parameter
        my_params[parameter]
        res := all[_]
        res.change.after[parameter] != res.change.before[parameter]
    ]
    num := count(modifies)
}
```

With this change, OPA will only find one set of variable assignments:

```
{resource_type: "servers", num: 1}
```

> Note, if OPA were to find other values for `resource_type` that would be fine because those would be different keys in the document produced by `modifies_instance_class`.

## 3rd problem: what if the parameter field is missing before or after?

There is one more problem to deal with. In the examples above, we assumed that looking up the field referred to by the `parameter` var would always return a value. What if this is not the case? What if one of the before or after objects are missing the field?

In this case, the reference `res.change.after[parameter]` or `res.change.before[parameter]` would be *undefined*. If either value is undefined, the expression `res.change.after[parameter] != res.change.after[parameter]` is also undefined (https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/#expressions-logical-and). If the expression is undefined, OPA cannot assert that it's true, so the result is not included in the result (or in this case, the array computed by the comprehension.)

Depending on the nature of the data, this may (or may not) matter. To deal with this we can extend the check to deal with the case where the field is undefined on one side (or both).

```
modifies_instance_class_V3[resource_type] = num {
    some resource_type
    resource_types[resource_type]
    all := resources[resource_type]
    modifies := [[res, parameter] |
        some parameter
        my_params[parameter]
        res := all[_]
        not same_or_both_undefined(res.change.after, res.change.before, parameter)
    ]
    num := count(modifies)
}

same_or_both_undefined(a, b, k) = true {
    a[k] == b[k]
}

same_or_both_undefined(a, b, k) = true {
    not a[k]
    not b[k]
}
```

> Note: In this case we have to use a helper function because want to express logical OR: https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/#logical-or.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

First issue is using `res.change.after.parameter` in this way will cause problems. That is using a key named "parameter" and not the variable. You'll have to do something like `res.change.after[parameter]`. That should avoid the first error.. But exposes the next (and bigger) issue:

`eval_conflict_error: object keys must be unique`

The issue being the way you are combining them where you have `my_params[parameter]` and counting the `modifies`. It is going to give you a `num` distinct to the `parameter` for each `resource_type` (ie, some resource type `x` may have a num of `0` for `instance_class` and a `2` for `identifier`), which is tricky with the way you are structuring the results as a map of `resource_type` to `num` (since there are potentially >1 num for each)

If you only care about the count you could do another comprehension that checks each parameter for each resource (maybe not the best option.. but works). An example of that working is here: https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/5T5TntBygd

```
modifies_instance_class[resource_type] = num {
    some resource_type
    resource_types[resource_type]
    all := resources[resource_type]
    modifies := [res |
        res := all[_]       # For each resource
        # Check if one of the params we care about changed
        changed_params := [p | p := my_params[_]; res.change.after[p] != res.change.before[p]]  
        count(changed_params) > 0
    ]
    num := count(modifies)
}
```

Note that this example isn't great for providing any kind of feedback about *what* changed, so as a helper it might be useful but mileage on it may vary.